# Python logger config is not impacting on the imported module

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have created a logger.py for formatting my python logger, which will have 2 different setup for logging error and info msgs in 2 different files.

```
import logging
import os

class Logger(logging.Filter):

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            logpath = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())+'/'
            self.info_logger = self.setup_logger('Normal logger', 'Infologger111.log')
            self.error_logger = self.setup_logger('Error logger', 'ErrorLogs2222.log')
        except Exception as e:
            print('[Logger __init__] Exception: ', str(e))
            raise

    def setup_logger(self, name, log_file, level=logging.DEBUG):
        try:
            handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
            handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
                '%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|p%(process)s|[%(pathname)s|%(name)s|%(funcName)s|%(lineno)d]|%(message)s',
                datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
            logger = logging.getLogger(name)
            logger.setLevel(level)
            logger.addHandler(handler)
            return logger
        except Exception as e:
            print('[setup_logger] Exception: ', str(e))
            raise
```

And I have a API_connector class in api_function.py file

```
import logging
logger = logging.Logger(__name__)
class API_connector(object):

    def __init__(self, data={}):
        logger.info("**********test log in API_connector")
```

Now I imported the Logger class as well as API_connector class both into my python code as below,

```
from logger import Logger
import api_function

class LogTest(Logger):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def test_func(self):
        print('inside test func')
        self.info_logger.info('test_func log message')
        self.error_logger.error('test_func error message ')
        api_function.API_connector()

if __name__=='__main__':
    ob=LogTest()
    ob.info_logger.info('main start')
    ob.test_func()
```

So the issue is 2 different files getting created and getting logged from my python code but the logging I kept in api_function file is not getting printed as my python code file does.
I want the same logger configuration to be impacted in the api_function file, by doing simply like this,

```
logger = logging.Logger(__name__)
```

How to make it printed in those 2 configured files with all the logger formatting I have configured?